# Is there an updating match counter which I can use as a prefix in the replace text?

Tags: regex, perl

In a perl regex, is there an updating match counter which I can use as a prefix in the replace text? For example, I want to replace each occurrence of `position` with `position 1`, `position 2` and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no predefined counter, but you can easily create one yourself:

```
my $i = 1;
s/position/ "position " . $i++ /eg;
```

(Using the `/e` flag to tell perl to parse the replacement part as a block of code, not a string.)

Answer (score 3):

Make your own counter. Declare a `state` in the replacement side of the substitution and increment it for each replacement. This is similar to other answers except for the scope of the variable:

```
use v5.10;

my $string  = 'position position position';

$string =~ s{position}{
    state $i = 0;
    $i++;
    "POS $i"
    }ge;

say $string;
```

The capture variables are available, so you can use `$1`, `$&`, and so on:

```
use v5.10;

my $string  = 'position position position';

$string =~ s{position}{
    state $i = 0;
    $i++;
    "$& $i"
    }ge;

say $string;
```

But, since you need v5.10 for `state`, you can use the `/p` switch and the `${^MATCH}` variable (a per-match rather than global version of `$&`):

```
use v5.10;

my $string  = 'position position position';

$string =~ s{position}{
    state $i = 0;
    $i++;
    "${^MATCH} $i"
    }gpe;

say $string;
```

And, you can do even fancier things in the replacement side:

```
my $string  = '123 abc 456 xzy red 137';

$string =~ s{(\d+|[a-z]+)}{
    my $_ = $1;
    state $letters = 0;
    state $sum     = 0;
    if( /[a-z]/ ) {
        $letters++;
        "($letters: $_)";
        }
    elsif( /\d/ ) {
        $sum += $_;
        }
    }ge;

say $string;
```

Comment: Won't that keep counting up even for different `$string`s?

Comment: Sure it keeps counting, but so does any counter unless you do something to make it not do that.

Comment: No, the other answers will restart from `1`.

Comment: Your lexical variable doesn't magically reset itself. Try it and post your answer. You'll see that you had to do something extra to reset your counter.

Comment: And, now explain the extra thing you did to reset the counter, because, as I said, you had to do something extra. When you realize that I'm right, perhaps you can remove the downvote too :)

Comment: I did nothing extra. I literally copy/pasted the code from here. (Also, that code doesn't "reset" anything because every execution of `my` creates a new variable.) But I'd be interested to see how you could get the `my $i` solution to not "reset" without changing the code.

Comment: No, you created a new scope and a new counter variable. Getting it to not reset is easy. Just do the operations in the same scope. Your answer doesn't show the extra thing you did and what people need to do to start from 1 on each substation. You left out most of your work but using the hidden assumptions of your hidden work to miss the other things you had to do to make it work.

Comment: The new scope isn't relevant. Creating a new counter variable isn't something "extra"; it's part of the code in the answer.

Comment: If you think stuff that you have to include beyond what you've shown isn't "extra", then there are problems beyond your understanding of Perl. The new scope is exactly relevant because what you claim doesn't happen without it.

Comment: OK, you've lost me. What is the stuff I have to include?

Comment: Well, I lost you before you first commented. Look at the code in your answer here, then look at the code you posted to that other site. The code you posted on the other site is much longer. Why? Because you need more to make it work. Without the new scope of each iteration of the foreach loop, your counter will not reset to 1 for each match. However, none of that shows up in your answer on Stackoverflow. It's something you have to add and it's relevant. Go back to your third party post and do it all in the same scope and see what happens. But, this is what I've been saying all along.

Comment: Notice what you did though. You explicitly reset the value of the variable before you used it again. As I've been saying, you have to do something extra to get it to do that, and you keep doing it. It works because you do extra work to make it work. If you turn on warnings, perl will bug you about the second variable declaration masking the first.

Comment: No, I never reset any variable in there. I also don't use variables "again". There's no extra code added. What are you talking about?

Comment: Look at the code. You have two lines that say `my $i = 1;`. I shouldn't have to say it, but you really need to start paying attention. It's your code and you don't even know what you wrote.

Comment: I also have two lines that say `s/position/ "position " . $i++ /eg`. What's your point?

Comment: Your point is that the counter will keep going, which is why you commented on my answer. But in your example, you reset the counter. You take a variable of the same name and give it a new value. Take out that second declaration of `$i` and try again. Try to keep up here.

Comment: No, taking out the second declaration would be doing something extra: It would remove code from the example. As I said above, every execution of `my` creates a new variable, which is why my solution works as-is no matter what context you place it in: At the top level, in a block, in a loop, in a sub, ... BTW, I've figured out a way to make a loop without opening a new scope as you requested: http://ideone.com/Di9k0t. It still works.

Comment: Notice in the goto that you once again initialize a new variable. You have to keep initializing it to make it work, which has always been my point. As for your answer here, code snippets and short explanations are often lacking in the things that person asking the question needs to know. Your confusion probably stems from your poor coding practice that using warnings will tell you about. So, let's leave it at that because I don't think you really care.

Comment: Yes, and creating and initializing a new variable is part of my answer. It's not something extra you have to add.

Answer (score 1):

something like this should do:

`$ perl -e '$string = "position position position"; $i=1; $string =~ s/(position)/"$1 " . $i++/ge; print $string'
position 1 position 2 position 3`

the trick here is to use the `e` option which will evaluate the replacement text as a Perl expression.